# NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for {"database"=>"car_rental_production", "username"=>"dev", "password"=>nil}:Hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I get that error when trying to deploy a rails 7 on render.com followed by:

```
 if url.nil? || url.start_with?("jdbc:", "http:", "https:")
```

I am quite new at development, please help.

Comment: Your error message pinpoints the error. You can confirm that with `Hash.instance_methods.include?(:start_with?) #=> false`. See [Module#instance_methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods).

Answer (score 1):

start_with? is a method for a String, but url is a Hash. If you want to run start_with? on one of the values contained in the Hash, you'll need to pass the key as well. For example:

```
url['database'].start_with?("car")
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in your error message, the method `start_with?` doesn't exist for an object of type Hash.

Following your error message, the real value of your variable`url` is the following Hash : `{"database"=>"car_rental_production", "username"=>"dev", "password"=>nil}`

Your code looks good but the real value of `url` seems to be a `Hash` instead of a `String`.

For your information, there is a method [respond_to?](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Object/respond_to%3F) which allows to ensure a method exists for an object before calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `url` variable points to a `Hash` and not a `String`.
The has contains String keys and String values.

So first you need to get the value that is associated with the database key:

`database = url["database"]`

and then run the check on this value.
If the key "database" is supposed to be always present, then you could also run

`url.fetch("database")`

which will raise an error, if missing. The value can still be `nil` though.

So full example looks something like:

```
url = {"database"=>"car_rental_production", "username"=>"dev", "password"=>nil}

database = url["database"]

if database.nil? || database.start_with?("jdbc:", "http:", "https:")
  puts "here"
else
  puts "there"
end
```

This will print out `there` since there is a value for the database, but it does not start any of the prefixes that you want to check.